# Find polar forms for $zw, \frac{z}{w}$, and $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I've a question regarding these exercises where you need to find the polar forms for $zw, z/w, 1/z$ and there's a square root involved, particularly my question is for the multiplication for the following problems:

1. $z=4\sqrt{3}-4i, w= 8i $
2. $z=2\sqrt{3}-2i, w= -1+i $
3. $z=4\sqrt{3+i}, w= -3-3i $

Could someone check if the following procedure is OK?

1. $z=4\sqrt{3}-4i, w= 8i $

First multiply each member as follows:

$ (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i $

$ (0+32)+(32\sqrt3 -0)i $

$ 32+\sqrt{3i} $

Then I calculated $ r $ and $ \theta $:

$ r= z = \sqrt{a^2 +b^2} $

$ a=32, b= 32\sqrt3 $

$ r= \sqrt{(32)^2 + (32\sqrt3)^2} $

$ r= \sqrt{1024 + (1024*9)} $

$ r= \sqrt{10240} = 101.19 $

And the Angle

$ \theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{32\sqrt 3}{32} $

$ \theta = 60° $

So the answer is

$ 101.19(\cos 60 + i \sin 60)$

---

2. $z=2\sqrt{3}-2i, w= -1+i $

$ 2\sqrt3*-1 - (-2*1) + ([2\sqrt3*1 + (-2*-1)]i$

$ (-2\sqrt 3 + 2) + (2\sqrt 3 + 2)i $

$ (2 -2\sqrt 3) + (2+ 2\sqrt 3)i $

$ r= \sqrt{(2-2\sqrt3)^2 + \sqrt(2+2\sqrt3)}^2$

$ r= \sqrt{(2^2-(2^2*3) + (2^2+(2^2*3)}$

$ r= \sqrt{(4-(12) + (4+12)} $

$ r= \sqrt 8 $

$ r= 2.82 $

$ \theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{2+2\sqrt 3}{2-2\sqrt3} $

$ r= 2\sqrt 2 = 2.82 $

$ \theta = 75.04 $

Answer would be:

$ 2.82(\cos 75.04° + i\sin 75.04°) $

Am I doing the operation $ r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $ correctly? Or any other error you could spot here?

Comment: The first one $(32\sqrt{3})^2=32^2(3)$

Comment: Word of advice: leave numbers exact instead of using decimal approximations.

Comment: You would find it easier if you converted $z$ and $w$ to polar form, at which point the magnitudes and arguments of $zw, z/w, 1/z$ can be found directly from those of $z$ and $w$. If you want to know how, go research it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First one,  the multiplication

$$ z=4\sqrt{3}-4i= 8\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2} =8( \cos \pi/6-i \sin \pi/6)= 8e^{-i \pi/6}$$

$$ z=8e^{-i \pi/6}$$

$$w= 8i = 8 e ^{i\pi/2}$$

Advantage of polar form is that you can multiply coefficients and add their arguments/exponents. That is why you should go for
polar form at the earliest opportunity.

$$ z\cdot w = 64  e^{i \pi/3}$$

and next for division you can divide coefficients and subtract their arguments/exponents.

$$ z / w =  e^{-i 2\pi/3}$$

The reciprocal $1/z$ is easier, you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

is $ \frac{1}{8e^{i\pi/6}} $ 

the answer for $ \frac{1}{z} $

Comment: No.you have to pay attention to the absolute value ( this is okay) and  the angle also.

Answer (score 0):

If $z = r_1 \exp(i \theta_1)$ and $w = r_2 \exp(i \theta_2)$, then $zw = r_1 r_2 \exp \left(i(\theta_1 + \theta_2) \right)$. Similarly, $z/w = \frac{r_1}{r_2} \exp \left(i(\theta_1 - \theta_2) \right)$.

If $z = 4\sqrt{3} - 4i$ and $w = -2+2i$ for example, you would first need to convert $z,w$ to polar form. First figure out which quadrants $z$ and $w$ are in. Then you can proceed: $z$ has magnitude $\sqrt{(4\sqrt3)^2+(-4)^2} = 8$, and argument $\arctan \left( \frac{-4}{4 \sqrt 3} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$ which makes sense. Likewise, $w$ hasmagnitude $\sqrt{(-2)^2+(2)^2} = \sqrt{8}$ and argument $\arctan \left( \frac{2}{-2} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ which does not make sense. To place the point in the correct quadrant, we need to add $\pi$ to the argument, which is just a reflection along the line $y = x$, so it preserves the dimensions of the right angled triangle. This gives us $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$.

Then $zw$ is just $8\sqrt{8} \exp \left(i(-\pi/6 + 3 \pi/4) \right)$, or $8 \sqrt{8} \exp(i \cdot 7\pi/12 )$. It is straightforward to convert this form into the form $r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Can you now use this method to calculate $zw,z/w,1/z$ in the exercise?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

is $ \frac{1}{8e^{i\pi/6} $ the answer for $ \frac{1}{z} $ ?